# Can’t reboot after using Minicom connected to a SIM7100E modem

Tags: debian, reboot, minicom

I am using a SIM7100E modem made by Qualcomm. It is a multi-band TDD-LTE/FDD-LTE/WCDMA/GSM/GNSS card.

Since this modem is capable of going into a state that is not even fixed by a reboot, but requires a power cycle, I would like to reset it using the command `AT+CPOF`.

So I launch `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB3` and type in `AT+CPOF` to which I get the reply `OK`.

I quit Minicom by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Q</kbd> followed by <kbd>enter</kbd>.

After this, when I try to `reboot` using this exact command, it just does nothing and hangs. It can be interrupted, though.

Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Immediately after attempting `reboot`, try: `$ dmesg | less`, hit `>` and then scroll backwards through the text (arrow up) - any clues in there?

Comment: FWIW: the reboot shouldn't be necessary IMO.

Comment: “Since this modem is capable of going into a state that is not even fixed by a reboot…” What does this mean? It goes to sleep or something like that and cannot get out of it without a reboot?

Comment: will do with dmesg..
means that sometimes, it loses its IP address and a reboot does not fix the issue, but pulling the power plug does

Comment: unfortunately less does not work anymore after said commands; it behaves like reboot:
the cursor moves one line down (no user@hostname is shown there) and stays there until interrupted